# How to store dataset row value as string?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have executed SQLquery using powershell and i would like to store the result in log file.

```
    $SelectQuery = "SELECT [$columnName] FROM [$DatabaseName].[dbo].[$TableName];"
    $Qresult= invoke-sqlcmd -query $SelectQuery -ServerInstance $srvInstance
    Log-Write "$Qresult"
```

(Log-write is a function which will add the contents to logfile)
But logfile shows as "System.Data.DataRow " which means $Qresult is not converted as string properly.

How to convert it into string and store in log file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Convert to `string` each `DataRow` like this:

`$Qresult = $Qresult| % { $_.$columnName` }